# I am getting this Error HH16: The directory C:\block\react-dapp contains files that could conflict: error when i run npx hardhat

Tags: reactjs, ethereum, hardhat

how do i solve this Error HH16: The directory C:\block\react-dapp contains files that could conflict:
i am using Hardhat for the first time and this error occurred when i run npx hardhat inside the project directory . i have done some searching here but none of the posts and answers solve the problem any assistance will be appreciated

here is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "react-dapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers": "^2.0.5",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle": "^2.0.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.4",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "chai": "^4.3.6",
    "ethereum-waffle": "^4.0.0-alpha.0",
    "ethers": "^5.6.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "hardhat": "^2.9.1"
  }
}
```

[image: here is the error message]

Comment: I faced this error too. The conflict arises because `hardhat` is also trying to create a file called `REAMDE.md` but one with thee same name already exists. A simple hack I used was to rename the old one to `README.md.old` and run `npx hardhat` again.

Comment: thanks @nishant it works for me i changed the REAMDE.md and run npx hardhat again and it works

Answer (score 0):

https://hardhat.org/errors/

HH16: conflicting files during project creation
You are trying to create a new hardhat project, but there are existing files that would be overwritten by the creation process.

Either try using a new directory name, or remove the conflicting files.

(Y)

Answer (score 0):

Because Hardhat create another Readme file so delete your readme file and do

```
npx hardhat
```

again. It will work properly.